# c# passing database and parameter to crystal report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I get this error

> The types of the parameter field and parameter field current values are not compatible.

when passing both database and parameter to Crystal Reports.

```
ReportDocument rd = new ReportDocument();

public string user;

public frmReport(string User)
{
        InitializeComponent();
        loadReport();
        this.user = User;
}

public void loadReport()
{
        rd.Load(@"C:\Users\Jeff Enad\Desktop\TEST1\Cebu Hallmark Hotel Management System\Cebu Hallmark Hotel Management System\cryReport.rpt");

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=dbCebuHallmark;Integrated Security=True");

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("GetAllReport", con);
        rd.SetParameterValue("UserPrinted", user); //This is the parameter
        da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        DataSet ds = new System.Data.DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "REPORT");

        rd.SetDataSource(ds);

        crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rd;
        crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
}
```

The `SetParameterValue()` is causing the error.

Can anyone help me to solve this problem? Should I add parameter in stored procedure or in dataset?

I just want to pass the user's name to the Crystal Report that has database.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the parameter and value in `SqlCommand` object in your `SqlAdapter`. Please see below for the updated code:

```
    public void loadReport()
    {
        rd.Load(@"C:\Users\Jeff Enad\Desktop\TEST1\Cebu Hallmark Hotel Management System\Cebu Hallmark Hotel Management System\cryReport.rpt");
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=dbCebuHallmark;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("GetAllReport", con);
        da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        DataSet ds = new System.Data.DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "REPORT");
        rd.SetDataSource(ds);
        rd.SetParameterValue("UserPrinted", user); //This is the parameter
        crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rd;
        crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
    }
```

Comment: I don't have `@UserPrinted` in the database only parameter in crystal report.

Comment: oh I got your question wrong. Apologies.
Can you try doing the SetParameterValue line after Setting datasource? I have updated the code above

Comment: what is the datatype of UserPrinted in reports?

Comment: The name of the user that I pass from Login to this Report.

Comment: In C# code, user is defined as a string (code: public string user;). What about UserPrinted in Reports?

Comment: I already solve the problem just now. I just did is to add `rd.SetParameterValue("UserPrinted", user);` in the `form_load`. Thanks for helping.