# Crystal Reports (VS 2019) not pulling new data from SQL Server on some computers?

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, crystal-reports

I have a WPF console app, written in C# and VS 2019.

I have a few Crystal Reports that have worked without any problems.

Now suddenly:

- If I run in Debug Mode, everything fine
- If I run on my computer (the one I develop on), everything is fine.
- When I deploy to a users computer, the report pulls the default data that I used to create the report, but not the data that I load in the following code:

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
{
    using (SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
    {
        adp.Fill(ds, "Ledger");
        report.SetDataSource(ds.Tables["Ledger"]);  
    }
}
```

As I said, on my own system, the program properly loads fresh data from SQL Server.

But on the other computer, it uses the default.

The same program loads another Crystal Report (inside the same CS file) and that one works fine.

- I have tried deleting the entire program and copying it over again.
- I cleared the folder in the `%AppData%`

I am at a loss.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can the other computer user access required table? If you save your report without data, does something improve?

Answer (score 0):

from cs file when you call crystal report, you need to pass the sqldetails/credentials, so it will connect that one (called run-time/dynamically assign db) , else it will connect what you configured in design time.

Second option which need one time when there is no luck that open report in crystal report, just verify database from topmenu in that location where you want to run.

Even though, if there is parameter, that also you can pass from c# code like companyid or employeeid etc.

```
 public void loadReport()
    {
        rd.Load(@"C:\Users\Jeff Enad\Desktop\TEST1\Cebu Hallmark Hotel Management System\Cebu Hallmark Hotel Management System\cryReport.rpt");
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=dbCebuHallmark;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("GetAllReport", con);
        da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        DataSet ds = new System.Data.DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "REPORT");
        rd.SetDataSource(ds);
        rd.SetParameterValue("UserPrinted", user); //This is the parameter
        crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rd;
        crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
    }
```

Refer this one [c# passing database and parameter to crystal report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34867850/c-sharp-passing-database-and-parameter-to-crystal-report) , [Crystal Report ask database parameter Login C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43414497/crystal-report-ask-database-parameter-login-c-sharp)

or just search in google "c# crystal report  set database and parameter"

Comment: I have done all of that, my conn variable is a connections to my database.
One thing I can try that you did that I did not was to Refresh the report at the end of filling the data.

Comment: Also, my code works fine on my system, but not on another system. 
And it works fine for one report but not another